# ANTLRv4 access node of child

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, children

I have the following ANTLR code:

```
expr : one=INT op=OP two=INT;
var : '$' n=STR ' ''='' ' e=expr ';'
```

I would like the `var` to be able to return `expr`'s values `$one`, `$two`, and `$op`. Is this possible?

Comment: In what form?  The value of `$e.text` will be the text of the matched `expr` rule. But somehow I doubt that is what you are asking for.

Comment: I would need to access something like `$e.text.one` to access the `expr`'s `one` value.

Comment: Need to provide significantly more context to get any meaningful answer. Do you want to access this value in the form of an parser action or predicate?  Or, in a walker?